# Firefox proxy authentication

Tags: firefox, proxy, user-accounts, authentication

I am using Firefox (Version 12) behind a proxy to access internet in a Windows XP computer. If I type in a wrong password at the proxy authentication prompt it will lock out my user account. Can this be due to Firefox retrying to authenticate the proxy? If so can I configure the number of retry times in forefox so that it will not lockout my user account?

Comment: more details please. What is your actual problem? What error do you have? What steps reproduce that error? Please post screenshots!